# Microsoft Access relationships for a library

Tags: database, ms-access, structure

I've been creating a normalised, basic structure for a microsoft access database. It looks like this. I want it to have first, second, and third normal form normalisation. Not concerned about adding more fields because I believe the basics are there.

Just by judging this picture does this fit in with the three rules of normalisation here? Have I missed out any relationships or is there any data redundancy? Pretty sure it's fine but any feedback would be appreciated!

[image: My proposed database relationship structure.]

Comment: As I mention, pretty sure it's fully normalised. Would just be great if any database folks could just check it's normalised correctly. Only concern I have is loans: I think it should be one to one because there's only 1 book and only 1 loan can be created from it, at a time, anyway.

Comment: Looks perfectly Normalized. The Junction table `Loans` look like they are a bit messy, but they actually are not. This is how you do it :)

Comment: in your scheme it is impossible for a `book` to have several authors`

Comment: @4dmonster for me in this example database thats how i wanted it, sorry should have stated

Answer (score 1):

To immediately answer your question, yes this is 3NF.

One flaw in your question is leaving out your intentions for how you're going to use this information. Why does a Library care about the course studied/length of course for a student? What if one record has "Biology", and the other is "biology" or "Biology 101" vs "Biology 102"?

Should there be a Course table that has a list of Courses? This would lead to a few other changes in your database design.

What if a Student extends their "Loan" for the same book. Are you going to just push back the `LoanUntil` field for that StudentID and BookID, or create a new `Loan` record? This leads me to my next question :
What if a book is overdue? I don't see any way for this database to handle that either. That is an important piece in a Library's infrastructure (and partly how they make money).

Hope this helps.